# Windows CMD Batch, START and output redirection

Tags: command-line, batch, redirection

I would like to run two programs simultaneously from a batch file, and redirect the first program's output into a text file like:

```
start python 1st.py arg1 arg2 > out.txt
start 2nd.exe %1 arg2 arg3
```

While the programs run as expected, all output is shown on stdout.

Comment: This ought to work. Without knowing anything, I wonder if 1st.py is doing something funny with output.

Comment: No, but it writes to stderr.

Comment: That's why—`>` only redirects stdout (I think). In any case, it looks like you already have what you need.

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is because you are redirecting the output of the start command and not python.exe, and there's no way to start something directly with a redirection when using start. You should just remove start entirely

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You might need to do it this way:

```
start cmd /c python 1st.py arg1 arg2 ^> out.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work for me (out.txt is not even created in the local directory)

Comment: I tested it with CScript and a VBscript, so the idea is sound. Are you doing something "extra" in your command line that's not listed here, like double quotes?

Comment: Sorry, something went awfully wrong - it works!

Comment: @Patrick Seymour, thank you for your answer! How can I do same thing without .bat file? This doesn't work from cmd: **python.exe ^> python_out.txt**. I had an error:
*python.exe: can't open file '>': [Errno 22] Invalid argument*.

Comment: Note that for append mode, >> needs to be escaped like this: ^>^>

Answer (score 9):

Additionally, if you want to redirect both stderr and stdout this works for me

> start call delay.bat ^1^> log.txt ^2^>^&^1

It seems every character basically needs to be escaped. This command normally looks like this:

> delay.bat 1> log.txt 2>&1

Answer (score 8):

Redirection is applied to the `start` command, but somehow not to the `cmd.exe` instance it runs.

If the `>` operator is escaped, everything should work:

```
start 1st.py arg1 arg2 ^> out.txt
```

(If you want to redirect stderr as well, use `2^>` for it.)

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work for me.

Comment: This wouldnt work because the redirection is meaningless here, you aren't starting a command, you're starting a program. You only escape when youre starting cmd.exe /c where you are starting a program and supplying a command to it and you need to make sure that it interprets it as being part of the command string being passed to cmd

Answer (score 8):

What did the trick for me was moving the command into a separate batch file:

```
rem this first batch file triggers the second one:
start the_second.bat arg1 arg2 out.txt
```

the_second.bat then looks like this:

```
python 1st.py %1 %2 > %3
```

Comment: This is a very inelegant workaround compared to the correct answer.

Comment: The "correct answer" didn't work for me with a similiar problem and I thought it might be a solution people at least might want to know about.

Comment: I have to disagree. Learning the correct way to escape characters in command is a much better idea.

Comment: Please teach me how to escape attaching output using >>.

Comment: I already told you. Read the accepted answer.