# Output redirection fails when using Start-Process to launch CMD with START /B

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, redirection

This is my `test.ps1`:

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'CMD.EXE' -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList '/C START /B PING.EXE google.com -t > logfile.txt 2>&1'
echo "Finished."
```

The test is an infinite ping to google, which is a good test for the conditions that I need to check:

1. Open the process in a new detached thread (= see the 'Finished' printed out + see PING.EXE alive in the process list + CTRL+C not killing PING.exe) **[OK]**
2. Collect the ping progress (that is: redirect standard input and standard error) to `logfile.txt` **[FAILS]** <= [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/338288) does not seem to work on my test, `logfile.txt` stays at 0 bytes

---

It is a convoluted solution, even though my final goal is relatively simple. What I finally want is to reproduce this linux cmd in powershell:

```
ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:5000 dotnet run > ${LOGFILE_PATH}.txt 2>&1 &
```

The difficult part in Windows seems to be to "*really* detach the process". `START /B` is the only windows functionality that I have found that really does that. But then I have the "output redirection" problem. And since I need it in a .ps1 file, I need to wrap it in `Start-Process`.

Answer (score 2):

You might be searching for one or more of the following
[Start-Process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6)
parameters:

> **-RedirectStandardOutput**
>
> Specifies a file. This cmdlet sends the output generated by the
>   process to a file that you specify. Enter the path and filename. By
>   default, the output is displayed in the console.
>
> **-NoNewWindow**
>
> Start the new process in the current console window. By default
>   PowerShell opens a new window.

Comment: I have worked with `Start-Process` alone, using both `-RedirectStandardOutput` and `-NoNewWindow`. The problem is `Start-Process` doesn't really detach the process. Testing `Start-Process -FilePath 'PING.EXE' -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList 'google.com -t' -RedirectStandardOutput 'logfile.txt'` will return to the command line, _but_ CTRL+C will kill PING.EXE in the process list. That is: the process is not really detached. I have found that `START /B` is the only solution to this problem.

Comment: Just to clarify (because the importance of the "strict process detachment is not obvious): I am calling this .ps1 from c# via `process.Start()`, and I need the `process.Wait()` to exit after the .ps1 is finished. This does not happen without "strict process detachment" in the powershell script.

Comment: Do you wish for a completely detached process? You are using both `-NoNewWindow` and  `START /B` which are meant to avoid it.

Comment: `START /B` is the only windows command I've found that reproduces the behavior of a linux detached background process using &. From the documentation: `/B: Start application without creating a new window. In this case Ctrl-C will be ignored - leaving Ctrl-Break as the only way to interrupt the application.`. Are there any alternatives? Google mainly proposes `-NoNewWindow` (which is not a _real_ detached background process), and in cmd.exe the proposed way was `START /B`, which works but is difficult to write in a powershell script (because of the output redirection issue).

Comment: Perhaps it would be simpler to invoke a `.bat` file that will contains the `ping` command (and do you really want it to ping forever even if the process fails?). I think that fleshing out the problem description in the post and how your software works would help, since I have difficulties following your logic.

Comment: I've tried the .bat approach, but after a few tries I've just failed miserably. The ping is just a test example for something that runs detached for a long time, in my real scenario it will be a dotnet web service (see linux cmd at the end of the OP). What I am trying to do is to create a deployment script for the dotnet web services, and the last line is "run the webservice in the background". This deployment script is at the same time launched by a c# program that polls a certain branch in the git repository, and launches the script (Process.Start(); Process.Wait();). See next comment:

Comment: If the process does not really work detached in the background, the Process.Wait() just waits forever (or more precisely, until I tell it to timeout).

Comment: You should remove `-NoNewWindow` in order to have a new window, and remove the `/B` again in order to start a new window. You are doing everything in one window so nothing is detached.